# JLS - Wait Set - Where is it?

Tags: java, wait, java-threads

The JLS for Java SE 11 Edition says in [chapter 17.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2):

> Every object, in addition to having an associated monitor, has an
>   associated *wait set*. A wait set is a set of threads.
>
> When an object is first created, its wait set is empty.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long,int)) of `Object.wait` says:

> This method causes the current thread (referred to here as *T*) to place
>   itself in the wait set for this object [...]
>
> The thread *T* is then removed from the wait set for this object [...]

Where is this *wait set* located?

The wording "has an associated *wait set*" and "wait set for this object" indicates it's not part of an object. And as far I can see it's not mentioned by the [`class` File Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html) of the JVM.

Is the *wait set* not part of the JVM? Is it part of the OS, i.e. the thread scheduler?

Is there an API to read the *wait set* (i.e. for monitoring purposes)? Something like `ThreadInfo` returned by `ThreadMXBean`?

Comment: The wait set should be part of the JVM and since it is a runtime info there's no need to place it into the class file format. Idk where exactly it is located but since `Object.wait(int)` is a native method the wait set might be located in the native parts of the JVM.

Comment: Being a runtime info makes sense why it's not part of the class file format.

Comment: `Thread.yield()` is declared native too and the documentation says: "A hint to the scheduler [...]". I would expect this to call an OS instruction. Maybe this also applies to `Object.wait()`. That's why I asked if the _wait set_ is part of the thread scheduler.

Comment: Well, I'd say it depends on the JVM implementation/target platform. It might be part of the OS' scheduler but it might as well be a part of the JVM's own threading system.